# Разница во времени в формате timestamp

Tags: php

Пытаюсь сделать таймер. Есть время окончания — 2015-05-13 17:00:00.

Нужно посчитать разницу между текущим временем и временем до окончания и запихнуть это всё в переменные:

```
$leftSeconds = кол-во  оставшихся секнд
$leftMinutes = кол-во оставшихся  минут
$leftHoures = кол-во оставшихся часов
```

чтоб в будущем эти переменные подставить в обратный таймер с JavaScript.

Comment: А в чем конкретно проблема-то?

Comment: Не могу получить разные значения в перменные - $leftSeconds=секунды, $leftMinutes = минуты и т.д.

Comment: Писал где-то так: `код $endTime = strtotime("2015-05-13 17:00:00"); $leftTime = $endTime - time(); ` Но проблема в том что на выходе получаю разницу во времени в Unix формате. А как дальше?

Comment: Это не разница времени в UNIX-формате. Это количество секунд.

Comment: Возможно, вы имеете в виду разницу между [датами/diff](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Вот хорошее средство для этого: [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.diff.php), через метод `diff` получаем [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/ru/class.dateinterval.php), в свойствах можешь получить разницу вплоть до секунд.
Особенно хорошо формировать вывод через функцию [`format`](http://php.net/manual/ru/dateinterval.format.php).

Пример:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("now");
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2015-05-14');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%Y лет, %R%M месяцев, %R%D дней, %R%H часов, %R%I минут, %R%S секунд');
```

Comment: TheDoctor : А если ТС нужно получить разницу больше, чем за сутки? [Смотрите, что у вас выходит](http://ideone.com/AVXLZc)

Comment: @romeo, Эм, всё верно, надо понимать что от чего отнимать, чтобы получить что нужно. Тем более там знаки плюса/минуса намекают.

Answer (score 1):

Буквальный ответ такой:

```
$diff = strtotime('2015-05-13 17:00:00') - time(); // разница в секундах
// gmdate() для того чтобы уйти от влияния timezone
list($hh, $mm, $ss) = explode(':', gmdate('H:i:s', $diff));

?>
<script>
var hh = <?= $hh ?>, mm = <?= $mm ?>, ss = <?= $ss ?>;
</script>
```

Но можно передать в JS просто метку времени, а не составляющие.
Нюанс в том, что Javascript работает с милисекундами, а PHP с секундами.

```
$time = strtotime('2015-05-13 17:00:00');
?>
<script>
var now = new Date();
var somedatetime = new Date();
somedatetime.setTime(<?= $time ?>*1000);
</script>
```

А уже в JS делайте какие-то вычисления.

Comment: в переменной $diff будет храниться число в формате timstamp , что-то типа 583872. Как его можно обрабатывать explode? Если же его перевести его в формат date() , что б в последующем распарсить фун-ей explode, то получим дату , небольшую дату начиная с 1970г (см. комменатрий под предыдущим ответом). Вот так  я в тупик и стал.

Comment: Просто попробуйте.

Comment: Очень похоже на мой `код: $leftTime = $endTime - time();
   $timeArr = Array('leftTime' => $leftTime , 
        'leftDate' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$leftTime),
        'leftSeconds' => date("s",$leftTime) ,
        'leftMinutes' => date("i",$leftTime), 
        'leftHoures' => date("H",$leftTime),
        'leftDays' => floor($leftTime / 86460),
        ); ` , так же как и ваш, не может правильно отобразить кол-во оставшихся дней.

Answer (score 1):

Универсальный подход (разница между длительными интервалами):

```
function diff(DateTime $datetime1, DateTime $datetime2 = null)
{
    if (!isset($datetime2)) {
        $datetime2 = new DateTime('now');
    }

    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2, false);
    $days = $interval->days;

    // calculate seconds
    $interval->s = $datetime2->getTimestamp() - $datetime1->getTimestamp();
    $interval->i = floor($interval->s / 60);
    $interval->h = floor($interval->s / (60 * 60));
    $interval->d = $days;
    $interval->w = floor($days / 7);
    $interval->m = floor($days / $datetime1->format('t'));

    return $interval;
}

// Если второй аргумент не задан, то берётся текущие время
$interval = diff(new DateTime('2012-02-15 12:00:00'));

echo "лет: {$interval->y}\nчасов: {$interval->h}\nминут: {$interval->i}\nсекунд: {$interval->s}";
```

[**Смотрите результат**](http://ideone.com/7AoJxp)

Comment: `$seconds = $dateTime1->getTimestamp() - $dateTime2->getTimesamp();` Зачем вручную проставлять свойства DateInterval?

Comment: @Etki Да вы правы, так на порядок чище. "Зачем вручную проставлять свойства DateInterval?" А почем нет? Вас смущает, что этот объект нативный? Если не ошибаюсь HHVM не умеет создавать динамически свойтва у нативных объектов, т.е.  на `$interval->w` (недели) должен ругнуться.

Comment: @Etki : Ну да, [я был прав](http://3v4l.org/lYJ71).

Comment: Меня смущает, что это нарушает SRP, и что в месяцы записывается неправильное число (а было правильное), и, возможно, нарушает работу объекта (понятия не имею, что будет в выводе `format()` после такой смены). Да и вообще, кроме `diff()` в этом случае ничего не нужно, объект не выполняет задачу переносчика абсолютных величин, это разница между двумя датами, а не энное количество секунд.

Comment: @Etki "и что в месяцы записывается неправильное число" нет, всё верно.  Вы наверно визуально перепутали: `i` - минуты, `m` - месяцы. И с [`format()` всё в порядке](http://ideone.com/C46JYo). Вы не могли бы дать ссылку на источник, чтобы почитать про SRP.

Comment: Да нет, неправильное. Разница между первым февраля и первым марта получится меньше месяца, а между первым мая и тридцать первым - больше. DateInterval потому и введен, что нельзя так с датами работать. SRP - Single Responsibility Principle, предполагает, что каждая сущность используется только по своему назначению, здесь же он превращается в структуру по передаче новых значений.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос немного размыт (нужно ли полное количество секунд / минут / часов или округленное до минут / часов / дней), поэтому сложно на него ответить. Я буду опираться на то, что требуется полное количество часов и округленное количество минут и секунд.

**UNIX Timestamp**

Первое, что можно сделать - это действительно работать с временной меткой UNIX (далее timestamp). Timestamp - это просто количество секунд, прошедших с 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. Таким образом, когда вызывается `time()`, возвращается просто целое число, содержащие эти секунды:

```
etki@vmint:~ > php -r 'echo time();'
1431539495
```

"UNIX-формата" не существует - это действительно не более чем целое число, означающее количество секунд, и работа с ним ограничивается простыми математическими операциями:

```
$targetTime = strtotime('2015-05-13 17:00:00'); // NB: временная зона не задана, будет использована текущая временная зона.
$currentTime = time();
$difference = $targetTime - $currentTime; // разница, она же количество секунд
$roundedSecondDifference = $difference % 60; // разница в секундах с точностью до минут
$minuteDifference = floor($difference / 60); // полная разница в минутах
$roundedMiunteDifference = $minuteDifference % 60; // c точностью до часа
// аналогично с часами
```

Таким образом можно получить  необходимые данные с минимальными затратами (математические операции крайне дешевы по сравнению с тем, о чем пойдет речь дальше).

**DateInterval**

Более верным решением задач с датами является работа с объектами класса DateTime и DateInterval. Эти два класса представляют собой дату и разницу дат соответственно. При простой работе с временной меткой возникает куча неразрешимых вопросов, например:

- Сколько месяцев составляет полученная разница?
- Для какой временной зоны (часового пояса) была создана та или иная метка?

Из-за особенностей календаря появляется очень много нетривиальных моментов, где просто невзможно работать с разницей дат как с числом секунд. Поэтому в языках программирования вводятся сущности, аналогичные DateTime и DateInterval. В вышеприведенном случае работа с DateTime будет максимально проста:

```
$targetTime = new DateTime('2015-05-13 17:00:00'); // также будет использоваться временная метка по умолчанию
$currentTime = new DateTime;
$difference = $targetTime->diff($currentTime); // получение объекта DateInterval
```

Дальше пойдут небольшие пляски с бубном. DateInterval представляет собой именно разность дат и не заточен под нужды вопроса и не представляет интерфейса для получения абсолютной разности в тех или иных величинах (кроме точного количества дней). Поэтому придется взять это количество дней и работать с ним:

```
$dayDifference = $difference->days;
$secondDifference = $dayDifference * 24 * 60;
// далее аналогично
```

В целом, работа с DateInterval считается более правильной (этот подход позволяет автоматически решить большое количество сложных случаев, для задач выведения "Х дней, У часов назад" он подходит как никто другой). Из однозначных плюсов - он сам вам скажет, сколько полных месяцев между двумя датами (это не самая тривиальная задача) и предоставляет интерфейс для форматирования результата, а при работе с DateTime гораздо проще контролирвоать временную зону и также форматировать результаты.

Comment: вот в чём загвоздка. Если будущее время отнять от текущего (оба числа в формате timestamp) то получим новое число, равное нескольким дням начиная с 1970г (например 1 января 14:54 1970г). Если же пробовать разницу времени (timestamp) делить на 60, 360 и т.д. то в результате получим значения - разница ВСЕГО времени в минутах, секундах, или же часах. Если из тупо запихнуть в таймер то получиться где-то так - осталось 4ч 240мин. 14400сек. Или я не прав? Вот в этом моменте я и запутался.

Comment: @dantey89, Там выше есть примеры с floor, это именно оно.